# Devise looking for wrong locale on Rails 4.0.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, internationalization, locale, deprecated

I've just updated to Rails 4.0.2 and I got the deprecation warning:

```
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
```

To get rid of the warning, I decided to set:

```
I18n.config.enforce_available_locales = true
```

in my **config/application.rb** file.

It worked pretty well on Development, all tests passed, and I was happy... Then I deployed my work in a staging server and it crashed!

Devise is looking for a locale **:pt**. All I have is a locale **:pt-BR**. I set it in my **application.rb**:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = 'pt-BR'
```

I don't know why devise is looking for **:pt** only. My locales in the **config** folder are: **pt-BR.yml** and **devise.pt-BR.yml**.

I tried to change the file name from **devise.pt-BR.yml** to **devise.pt.yml** (and inside from pt-BR to pt) and it worked.

I had to go back and set:

```
I18n.config.enforce_available_locales = false
```

to make it work.

I have two questions:

1 - Why this is not happening on the tests and on development?

2 - Why Devise is asking for **:pt**, if I'm setting the default locale as **:pt-BR** in my config?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using devise-i18n as well or just devise?  It may be that devise is looking for strings that are not defined in your locale files, and so is falling back from pt-BR to pt, triggering the error.  devise-i18n includes pt-BR, so assuming it's complete, adding it to your Gemfile would avoid this issue.

Comment: That worked fine! I added the gem and it worked. Thanks! But I still don't know why it is not appearing in development mode... Any idea?

Comment: Just posted my thoughts as an answer, along with the content of my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add devise-i18n to your Gemfile to get the pt-BR locale file for the Devise strings.  This fixes the production problem.

As for why you're not seeing the issue in development, it may be because you're not triggering the specific I18n.t lookup - you need to narrow it down.  Some Devise string is triggering this, and I suspect it won't cause an error until that string gets looked up.  You need to narrow down the exact set of actions that causes the issue.  If it's failing on startup, there might be some production eager loading going on that triggers the issue.